# Arduino Leonardo - Using ICSP pins for serial

Tags: softwareserial, arduino-leonardo, icsp

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the ICSP header pins on the Leonardo as GPIO pins, for example for software serial, and how to address them. I've a project which needs all available I/O pins, and I could use having serial comms on those "extra" pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.*/variants/leonardo/pins_arduino.h`:

> ```
> // Map SPI port to 'new' pins D14..D17
> #define PIN_SPI_SS    (17)
> #define PIN_SPI_MOSI  (16)
> #define PIN_SPI_MISO  (14)
> #define PIN_SPI_SCK   (15)
>
> static const uint8_t SS   = PIN_SPI_SS;
> static const uint8_t MOSI = PIN_SPI_MOSI;
> static const uint8_t MISO = PIN_SPI_MISO;
> static const uint8_t SCK  = PIN_SPI_SCK;
> ```

Those are the pin names and numbers you can use. Note that `SS`/17 is connected to the RX LED.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it as soon as I have some time to spare! ;)

Comment: It works, though SoftwareSerial don't seem to be able to manage baud rates of 115200 bps, which I need.. :$